# $scope undefined in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I'm creating an Angular app for learning (I'm all new to Angular) and currently stuck at this point.

Following is my Angular controller

```
cookingPad.controller('RecipeCreateController', function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.recipeSave = function($scope, $http){
    //code
  }; 

});
```

Following is my form

```
<form id="signup-form_id" ng-submit="recipeSave()">
  //some html
  <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="recipeFormData.name" id="name" class="form-control input-lg no-border-radius" placeholder="Name">
  // some more html
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="save1" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save"></i> Save</button>
</form>
```

So when I enter something in the text box and click `save` it comes inside the `recipeSave` function. but when I check the `$scope` variable with chrome dev tools, it shows it as

`$scope
undefined`

What could be the reason? Everything else in my Angular works im on Angular 1.2.4, I found several SO questions but none of them works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't re-declare the controller args in `recipeSave`:

```
$scope.recipeSave = function() {
```

Make that change and things should start working. Your template is explicitly invoking `recipeSave()` with no arguments, and you want to access your controller arguments via closure anyway, which will work fine.

Comment: @Peter Lyons, thanks got it working... yours and Seminda's example

Comment: @Seminda, thanks got it working with your example, BTW I think I know u back in SL, did u work at DPIT ?! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the recipeSave method having $scope and $http as arguments. Dependency Injection works on the Controller/Service/Filter/etc level, atributes from different scopes as recipeSave won't solve dependency injection.

In other words, on the view you are not passing parameters when you execute the recipeSave function, so the function gets undefined as the value of both parameters.

Cheers